# Can I use parallel.ForEach to call different functions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have a foreach loop that runs. I am looking into Parallel functions. Is it possible to convert the following code to use parallel programming?

```
int result ;
int counter;
foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {
    switch(dr["Gender"].ToString()) {
        case "Male":
            result = functionMale(dr["Gender"].ToString());
            counter += result;
            break;
        case "Female":
            result = functionFemale(dr["Gender"].ToString());
            counter += result;
            break;
        default:
            result = functionUnkown(dr["Gender"].ToString());
            counter += result;
            break;
    }
}
```

Based on what I have looked into I only have the following so far.

```
Parallel.ForEach(ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), dr => {
    var result = functionMale(dr["Gender"].ToString();
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Here is a link to aggregation in a parallel environment in C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963547.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You could use `AsParallel` and `Sum`:

```
Func<string, int> calculateGender =
    gender =>
    {
        // nb: I don't know why you pass the gender to the method, but
        // I've left your intent as-is
        switch (gender)
        {
            case "Male":   return functionMale(gender);
            case "Female": return functionFemale(gender);
            default:       return functionUnknown(gender);
        }
    };

int counter = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                          .AsParallel()
                          .Sum(dr => calculateGender(dr["Gender"].ToString()));
```

Comment: I am bit confused. @Dave is doing the same thing. so which is faster ?

Comment: @PankajGarg: I don't know, likely no difference in practice.

Comment: It's probably exactly the same, behind the scenes.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: This would reduce process time?

Comment: @MrM: this all depends on how many rows you have, how long `AsEnumerable` takes, how long each of the gender calculations take, etc etc. Sometimes workloads are no faster parallelized, and sometimes they are even slower. You likely won't know without trying.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this, in a more functional style:

```
var counter = 
    ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .AsParallel()
    .Select( dr => {
        var gender = dr["Gender"].ToString();

        switch(gender) 
        {
            case "Male":
                return functionMale(gender);
            case "Female":
                return functionFemale(gender);
            default:
                return functionUnkown(gender);
        }
    })
    .Sum();
```

Comment: Is it like selecting all records in a list first(internally) and then the sum function ?

Comment: Yes - but select is called "as it goes" - so it's probably going to have the same performance profile to the other answer above from sixlettervariables

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's entirely possible. Parallel.ForEach isnt doing any kind of specific magic in this instance (other than the threading), so it would just look like this:

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.AsEnumerable().AsParallel().Sum(x =>
  {
       DataRow dr = x as DataRow;

       switch(dr["Gender"].ToString())
       {
           case "Male":
             // Stuff
           case "Female";
             // Stuff
           default:
             // Stuff
       }

       return counter;
  });
```

This should aggregate all the values of the functions, because addition is commutative.

Comment: They do have such a dependency; he's aggregating the data.

Comment: Updated with the counter code; my bad, I didnt see the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

The PLINQ approach is a lot easier, but just to round out the answers here is how you would do this with `Parallel.ForEach`.

```
int counter = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(),
  () => /* subtotal initializer */
  {
    return 0; 
  },
  (dr, state, subtotal) => /* loop body */
  {
    switch(dr["Gender"].ToString()) 
    { 
        case "Male": 
            subtotal += functionMale(dr["Gender"].ToString()); 
            break; 
        case "Female": 
            subtotal += functionFemale(dr["Gender"].ToString()); 
            break; 
        default: 
            subtotal += functionUnkown(dr["Gender"].ToString()); 
            break; 
    }
  },
  subtotal => /* subtotal accumulator */
  {
    Interlocked.Add(ref counter, subtotal);
  });
```

Here is how this works. The first lambda expression initializes the local subtotal bins for each worker the TPL doles out. The second lambda expression executes once for each item in the collection and updates the local subtotal bin. The third lambda expression combines the local subtotal bins into the final total.

One interesting difference between using `Parallel.ForEach` and `AsParallel` with an aggregate is in the way the subtotals are accumulated into the final value. `Parallel.ForEach` does this operation on a worker thread thus the need for the thread-safe operation `Interlocked.Add`. `AsParallel` uses the same paritioning strategy, but accumulates the subtotals on the callers thread.